# Duplicate meta descriptions when category has multiple pages

Tags: meta

Does anyone know how to solve the problem of duplicate meta descriptions appearing when a category has multiple pages?

For example:

- Category: Telephones
- Pages: 5 pages

All 5 pages end up with the same meta description, titles and keywords. Only the content is changeable?

Comment: All such information is part of the template and not part of crafts own setup

Comment: Ah ok, so we would need to look at modifying the theme, rather than blaming it on the Craft CMS platform itself?

Comment: Craft doesn't include, advocate, or have a default method for displaying metadata of any kind - that's up to whoever builds out the templates.

Comment: Craft doesn't have 'themes' it has templates. If you look in your ```<head>``` you can see where the information is coming from

Answer (score 2):

I would **add custom fields to your category group**, for META Descriptions. This would allow you to display meta data when on a 'category home page'.

Then on a single entry page, the entry-type custom fields for meta data would be used.

See this example/answer: [How do I define an entry's META description?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13682/how-do-i-define-an-entrys-meta-description/13683#13683)