# How do I define an entry's META description?

Tags: templating, meta

I'd really like some help with Craft CMS, that's probably a very basic thing to achieve, but I've so far got no idea how to. In another post about SEO, I saw something like this written:

```
<meta name="title" content="{% if title is defined %}{{ title }}{% endif %}">
<meta name="description" content="{% if description is defined %}{{ description }}{% endif %}">
```

The first part, regarding the title, is in the _layout.html by default. And, in the CMS, above each entry's body, I have managed to display a box for the user to enter a title.

BUT, were I to add the second part, regarding the description, I have so far been unable to find out how in the CMS, I can add a box for the user to enter a description.

Thanks in advance for any help that anyone can provide.

With kind regards,

Mark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Title field will be a part of every entry 90% of the time ('Singles' don't need a Title).

To add a custom field in Craft:
**Settings** > **Fields** > (create a field)

To add the new field to a content type:
**Settings** > **Sections** > (click the "Edit content-type" link to the right) > (drag your new field into the blue box) > hit Save.

---

I like to create a separate custom field for each e.g. "**Meta Title**" and "**Meta Description**" - I then add these to a separate tab within a given **content-type**. (see attached)

[image: SEO fields]

Normally, I leave the SEO fields optional.

Then, in _layout.html:

```
<title>{% block entryMetaTitle %}{% endblock %}{{ siteName }}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{% block entryMetaDescription %}{% endblock %}">
```

The block tags inherit content from an individual template e.g. **domain.com/news/news-article-slug**, will make use of a single-entry template e.g. **craft/templates/news/_entry.html** which will contain:

```
{% extends "_layouts/_layout" %}

{% block entryMetaTitle %}{% if entry.metaTitle %}{{ entry.metaTitle}} | {% elseif entry.title %}{{ entry.title}} | {% endif %} News | {% endblock %}
{% block entryMetaDescription %}{% if entry.metaDescription %}{{ entry.metaDescription}}{% else %}{{entry.summaryText}}{% endif %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
... 
{% endblock %}
```

The above will display any content which the client decides to add to the custom fields, OR if nothing has been added the template will display the entry **Title** + **Summary Text** (in this case)

This post might also help you to define your own approach: [How do you handle SEO on your site?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2986/how-do-you-handle-seo-on-your-site)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Apologies for taking so long to come back. Been away. I'm guessing the contents of the `entryMetaDescription` block also work if it was just placed into _layout.html? So, for example: `<title>{% if entry.metaTitle %}{{ entry.metaTitle }} | {% elseif entry.title %}{{ entry.title }} | {% endif %}{{ siteName }}</title>`

Comment: It would, however I prefer having it in individual templates as it allows a little more control in cases where the the custom-field names might differ or not exist at all for a given content-type.

Comment: ... and, additionally, if there's multiple channels, you might want to display the name of that channel as part of the title, something that wouldn't be so easily achieved with my last comment ...